# Automate Login process for LinkedIn for API to retrieve access code to exchange for access token

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm working on a work project that will get the company's LinkedIn profile metrics i.e posts,followers and likes. I understand i'll need to use the "Advertising API" to get access to those endpoints. The main issues is the the data will be collected and then will be imported to a sql database, which will run daily. The first thing I have to get the access token is to login manual. Is there a way to automate the login process?

When I was looking around a lot of people say there are ways and they provided codes for it but those are 5+ years old and I'm not to sure if that will still work today. Other people were saying this will not work as it goes against LinkedIn TOS. When I was reading it mainly was talking about posting. It probably says somewhere about automate logins in the TOS I'm not sure where it says it.